# how to automate html button in Microsoft access vba

Tags: javascript, html

hi friends i am 100% New to Html that why i can't automate the browse button in the following code

My VBA code is:

```
 IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("PersonalPhoto").Click

 <html>
  Select...</span>
  <input id="PersonalPhoto" name="PersonalPhoto" type="file" />
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `getElementsByClassName` then only id is set for your element you should use something like `IE.Document.getElementById("PersonalPhoto").Click`

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?54830-how-to-automate-a-label-button-in-vba&p=336515#post336515

Comment: well the button is hidded with the div classes that's why i am unable to automate the click please check the source code <div class="t-widget t-upload"><div class="t-button t-upload-button">   <span>Select...</span><input id="PersonalPhoto" name="PersonalPhoto"  type="file" /></div></div>